# axis call soap webservice by sending parameter with namespace

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I want to invoke a soap webservice method by Java. But I can't generate the xml includes parameter with namespace.
like:

`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <sendMsg xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <as_xml xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">msg</as_xml>
        </sendMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

What I can generate is like:

`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <sendMsg xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <as_xml>msg</as_xml>
        </sendMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

Please tell me how to do?
Here is my code:

```
    Service service = new Service();
    try {
        String namespace="http://tempuri.org/";

        Call call = (Call)service.createCall();

        call.setOperationName(new QName(namespace, methodName));
        call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new URL("http://192.168.1.1/webservice_app/webservice.asmx"));

        call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
        call.setSOAPActionURI(namespace + "sendMsg");
        call.setEncodingStyle(null);
        call.setProperty("sendXsiTypes", Boolean.FALSE);
        call.setProperty("sendMultiRefs", Boolean.FALSE);

        call.addParameter(new QName(namespace, "as_xml"), XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);

        call.setReturnType(XMLType.XSD_STRING);

        String xmlResult = (String)call.invoke(new Object[]{"msg"});

        return xmlResult;
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Is there anything configuration that I miss?
Please help.